# While in other while using fetch_array() in PHP

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Can't find solution for this so i'm posting new question. As thread name say, i want to use while in other while when using fetch_array in PHP. I want to display info about user in every post.

My example code:

```
<?php
$users_query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$users_result = mysqli_query($db, $users_query);

$posts_query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$posts_result = mysqli_query($db, $posts_query);

while($row1 = $posts_result->fetch_array()) {
echo '<div class="post"><div class="user-info">';
    while($row2 = $users_result->fetch_array()) {
        echo $row2["user_name"]." ".$row2["user-posts-count"];
    }
echo '</div>'.$row1["message"].'</div>';
}
?>
```

It's just example but showing what i want. Second while executed only once, so info about user in post is displayed only in first post. Any solution?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english, Adrian.

Comment: please post your database schema. is there a relation between users and posts?

Comment: Once you've iterated over `$users_result`, that's it.  That result no longer has any more records to fetch.  Instead, once you get that result, iterate over it and put all of its results into an array.  Then you can re-iterate over that array from the beginning as many times as you like.

Comment: You may instead want to try getting the posts and left join the users table, and get the data you need that way.

Comment: What you are trying to do? How you are trying to show post? Does each post have a single user?

Comment: use the join query to get better results use the common id for join

Comment: @Gunaseelan noo, just want to display who add post.
aynber and KMS okay will try.

Comment: @a̲̅d̲̅r̲̅n̲̅ Have you tried what KMS and aynber said?